# the command " Get-Command -Module Defender" has no output

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to disable Windows defender in an old build of Windows 10 (en_windows_10_pro_10240_x64_dvd) without activating windows update,

The problem I'm facing is that the usual powershell commands to do that don't work, the command `Get-Command -Module Defender` has no output!

output of `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10240  16384
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain what you have tried so far. Also be more specific as to what Windows 10 you are using (Home, Pro, Enterprise) and what you mean by `old build`. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i added the version, hope that helps

Comment: en_windows_10_pro_10240_x64_dvd is the name of the ISO file and **not** the Windows build version

Comment: 10240 is the build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Defender module is not installed then.
You can try disable it using the registry. Run this as Administrator. The computer needs to be restarted for the new setting to take effect:

```
$regpath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender"
if (!(Test-Path $regpath -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft" -Name 'Windows Defender' -ItemType Container | Out-Null
}
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath -Name "DisableAntiSpyware" -Value 1 -Type DWord
```

You can enable Defender later bu using

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath -Name "DisableAntiSpyware" -Value 0 -Type DWord
```